# How do I get login and password for Reporting Services?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, authentication, passwords, set

I installed reporting services, but when I access it throught localhost\reports I'm asked for a login and password, but I don't know what login and password are. 
I was experimenting with reporting services configuration manager and trying to enter some login names but with no success. I found one combination of login and password that seemed to feet: login: .; pass: 12345; but after entering the login and password the screen of the browser just left blank.
 Where and how I can retrieve the login and password? What are the steps to set a new login and password for reporting services?

Comment: A link to [Identity and Access Control](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522824.aspx). I hope this can help.

Comment: In windows 2008 try running IE in admin mode

Comment: @danihp: thanks for the link, in there I found an article about granting users access for accessing reporting services, but in order to do this one have to be already able to enter reporting services throught browser... and I can't do even that.

Comment: @u07ch: I tried tunning IE, Chrome and Firefox as admin with no success.

Comment: Have presupposed that you set the server up through the Configuration manager all the way to the end. If you can't connect through IE Load Management Studio; change the server type to reporting services can you connect through management studio? Add your user to the content Manager list. If this doesn't work I would start again on the Configuration manager install.

Comment: @u07ch: I tried to connect (login) to report server throught management studio and seems the login process wants to run for forever... It connects, connects, ..., and nothing happens. Any thoughts about this? I have already reinstalled SQL Server 2008 3 times, it comes with Configuration manager already.

Comment: In my previous experience when installing reporting services either 2005 or 2008 the local admin account for that machine will automatically be allocated the admin account for SSRS.  So l have previously logged into the machine using the Admin account open the browser went to localhost\reports and l got the Report Manager.

Have you tried using the local admin user name and password when prompted?  It is possible to use forms authentication with SSRS.  The default installation uses windows account authentication.

Comment: @BobF: If you are talking about admin account, I have tryed to login using VADIM\Vadim (also Vadim and VADIM) as login name (name of my PC) and password left blank (I have no password) and result is the same - reporting services asks for a password again.

Comment: You need to go through the Reporting Services Configuration manager application from start to end to activate the software. My guess is that part of the config is corrupt. If you can't get to the last step or it still doesn't work work and you aren't going to lose anything; drop and backup the existing reporting services databases and start again.

Comment: @u07ch: thank you for your tries, but I'll think I'll give up this topic... it takes me to solve it too much time. Thanks for help guys, best I could do is to add you a bit of reputation thorought upvoting your posts.

Comment: The default login is usually your pc_name\username and password. Make sure that your account is an admin in your pc, else add your account to the admins list.